# Django: Getting complement of queryset

Tags: python, django, orm

I get a queryset for a certain model and I'd like to get its complement, i.e. all instances of that model that are *not* in the aforementioned queryset.

How can I do that?

Comment: It would help to have the Django queryset chain you want the complement of, in order to give you the most precise way to get that complement.

Comment: I want something that works for any queryset.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short solution**

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(...) # qs with objects to exclude
result = Model.objects.exclude(pk__in=qs.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

**More DRY solution**

However, if you want to use the logic many times, I would suggest to encapsulate it in a method. Here is an example I personnaly used in a custom queryset:

```
class QuerysetUtils:
    def get_queryset_complement(self, method):
        return self.exclude(pk__in=method().values_list('pk', flat=True))


class ExpirableQueryset(QuerysetUtils, models.query.QuerySet):
    def expired(self):
        return self.filter(expiration__lte=timezone.now())

    def unexpired(self):
        return self.get_queryset_complement(self.expired)
```

Comment: note that this gets executed as a subquery, i.e. the list of all ids to exclude is never generated (which would otherwise be a potential performance hit)

Comment: Is this the most succinct solution?

Comment: Maybe there's a better one for your use case but then it would be useful, as @Chris Pratt said, that you show us some code....

Comment: @RamRachum - Well guess then the solution above should be the simplest; and as second pointed out that the database will only be hit once as django will get the pks to exclude in a sql-subquery...