# How to update a queryset that has been annotated?

Tags: django, orm

I have the following models:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Book(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey('Work')
```

I am attempting to update some rows like so:

```
qs=Work.objects.all()
qs.annotate(Count('book')).filter(Q(book__count__gt=1)).update(visible=False)
```

However, this is giving an error:

DatabaseError: subquery has too many columns
LINE 1: ...SET "visible" = false WHERE "app_work"."id" IN (SELECT...

If I remove the update clause, the query runs with no problems and returns what I am expecting.

It looks like this error happens for queries with an annotate followed by an update. Is there some other way to write this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without making a toy database to be able to duplicate your issue and try out solutions, I can at least suggest the approach in [Django: Getting complement of queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820113/django-getting-complement-of-queryset?rq=1) as one possible approach.

Try this approach:

```
qs.annotate(Count('book')).filter(Q(book__count__gt=1))
Work.objects.filter(pk__in=qs.values_list('pk', flat=True)).update(visible=False)
```

Comment: I don't actually need the complement. The query is returning the correct rows, but the problem is that I can't update them.

Comment: Right.  My point is that you can use the same basic approach to get an unannotated queryset that should be bulk-updateable.

Comment: @jess: I just edited to include an example of what I meant.  Let me know if that works

Answer (score 7):

You can also clear the annotations off a queryset quite simply:

```
qs.query.annotations.clear()
qs.update(..)
```

And this means you're only firing off one query, not one into another, **but don't use this if your query relies on an annotation to filter.** This is great for stripping out database-generated concatenations, and the utility rubbish that I occasionally add into model's default queries... but the example in the question is a perfect example of where this would not work.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Oli's answer: If you need your annotations for the update then do the filters first and store the result in a variable and then call filter with no arguments on that queryset to access the `update` function like so:

```
q = X.objects.filter(annotated_val=5, annotated_name='Nima')
q.query.annotations.clear()
q.filter().update(field=900)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've duplicated this issue & believe its a bug with the Django ORM. @acjay answer is a good workaround. Bug report: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25171

Fix released in Django 2 alpha: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19513