# I want to use the django ORM to get a complement from two tables

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset, set-theory

I aready have checked this question  [Getting complement of queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820113/django-getting-complement-of-queryset/). But, it didn't work. It seems like it's only extracting one field in the result.

I have the following two tables:

**table A**

```
   001 a 
   002 b
   003 C
```

**table B**

```
   001 a
   002 b
   003 c
   004 d
   005 e
```

My gaol is get the complement like this:

**complement**

```
   004 d
   005 e
```

How to use the ORM to get this result?

**the models**

```
class WordBase(models.Model):
    number  = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
    word    = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    belong  = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    mean    = models.TextField()
    example = models.TextField()
class PersonalRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    number =  models.CharField(max_length=128)
    begtime= models.CharField(max_length=128)
    endtime = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True,)
    lasttime = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True,)
    times = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the link you provided should be correct. Basically what you need to do is exclude set A from set B.

```
setA = MyModel.objects.filter(…)  # Query for items belonging in set A
setB = MyModel.objects.filter(…)  # Query for items belonging in set B

# setA and setB are QuerySets, ans as such does not query the database
# until the data is actually needed. Thus you can just add further
# delimitations. The below lines does the same thing, somewhat differently.

complement = setB.objects.exclude(pk__in=[o.id for o in setA])
complement = setB.objects.exclude(pk__in=setA.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

As you can see what you need to do is exclude from setB any objects who's `pk` is in the specified list. `[o.id for o in setA]` and `setA.values_list('pk', flat=True)` are two different ways of computing such a list from the previously created query sets (which both hits the database in order to construct the list, obviously).

Comment: It still didn't work :(                                                                                       this is my code `<br>PersonalRecord_set = PersonalRecord.objects.filter(book = current.book,id = i_d)          </br>WordBase_set = WordBase.objects.filter(belong = current.book)
                      </br>new_words = WordBase_set.exclude(number__in=[o.number for o in PersonalRecord_set])[:1]`              Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: Oh, you are trying to calculate a complement between two different models (`PersonalRecord` and `WordBase`). My answer, and the linked question, assumes they are two sets of the same model. It's hard to tell without looking at your models, but I guess the exclusion should work anyway though, given there are actually objects inside your sets. Try running the queries manually in the [django shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) and make sure both sets have objects in them.

Comment: Does the query produce an error, or just an unexpected set? Do both `PersonalRecord` and `WordBase` have the number field on them?

Comment: It does not produce any error, PersonalRecord and WordBase have the number field both have number field.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to simplify your queries and run the in the django shell to try to understand what is happening and why. The set complement code I posted is in deed correct (I've tried it), so perhaps something is missing in your data. The query you posted will filter out from `WordBase_set` any `` objects having a number equal to a number on any of the objects in `PersonalRecord_set`. Is that what you intended for?

Comment: Using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#q-objects) you could easily construct sets similar to the example output you posted. Try your queries on two such sets and try to work out what's not working as expected.